How to power 2 MG996R towerpro servo
I am a beginner and tried powering MG996R Tower Pro (180 deg Metal Gear) Servo from Arduino UNO and ended up hibernating the host PC.
I want to power 2 such motors (in parallel configuration) for lets say 10 minutes a day at a time. What is the best solution to power it. I have learned the hard way that Arduino UNO's 5 V pin is not enough and it may have damaged my board too.
Should I use a 6 V charging adapter and cut off its end connect it to the motor? Should I use a capacitor? What am I supposed to do to power 2 such motors simultaneously? Also if possible provide a schematic of how to connect my motors (series or parallel) with the power supply. Datasheet : https://www.towerpro.com.tw/product/mg996r/
Side-question: How to check if my Arduino board is damaged after drawing too much current from servo because right now it works fine and is not heating and nothing seems charred.

These servos can draw a good deal of current when moving quickly or drawing high loads.
You can find that value under "Stall current" on the datasheet. That's the highest one of these motors will draw if stalled. In the case of these servos it's 1.4A -- For two servos that's almost 3A
A generic USB port can supply ~500mA (0.5A) of current. A USB 3 port might get you 3A though your Arduino isn't built to handle more than 1A trough the USB port.
For your case I'd suggest getting a good 5V power brick with about 3A or more. That way you can be sure that your servos won't kill the power brick if they ever stall. I suggest using 5V instead of 6V as that supply can also power the Arduino.
As for the wiring, the best option for flexibility and power is to attach the power supply to the 5V and GND of your Arduino as well as Red and Brown servo wire. That way the power brick can run both the arduino and servo together and you don't need a seperate supply for the Arduino.
You will need to figure out which of the power brick's leads are positive (5V) and negative (GND).

Side answer: If your Arduino board was damaged due to a high current load it would likely not run at all.

Could you please share a link of a suggested power supply which i should buy?

@AdityaJain We don't do product recommendations here. They are very volatile and region specific. But you can just go to the website of your favorite retail store and search for "5V 3A power supply". Every power supply, which is rated with 5V and 3A (or higher ampere) will fit, preferably one, that you can directly plug into a wall outlet.
